Save date from cell G18 into file name
Sub SaveWithWEDate()
    
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim WEdate As String
    WEdate = G18
    
    fileName = "WE " & WEdate & " WEEKLY SUMMARY"
    
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    
End Sub

I cannot get the text from cell G18 into my file name. It saves as "WE Weekly Summary"
I also tried using the cell number in the text string.
I am using this to save a template to a macro enabled excel workbook.
I have used this before with the actual date but my sheet calculates the week ending date as the Sunday.
I copied the Sunday date into a helper cell G18 with the cell format YYYYMMDD.

WEdate = ActiveSheet.Range("G18").Text

@SpectralInstance The problem with using .Text is that if your column is too narrow and is showing ###### then that's what's returned.  Better to use .Value, .Value2 or just leave it as .Range("G18").   What is the difference between .text, .value, and .value2?

The underlying value of your helper column is still a numerical date formatted to show "YYYYMMDD".  Reading the TEXT value of the cell might return ######.
Read the value into your procedure as a date and format it within the code so it can be used in the filename.
Sub SaveWithWEDate()

Dim fileName As String
Dim WEdate As Date
WEdate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G18").Value2

fileName = "WE " & Format(WEdate, "YYYYMMDD") & " WEEKLY SUMMARY"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

End Sub


Works perfectly. I learned.
